# How to make a Pandas DataFrame from a dictionary that has values that consists of arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Currently I have a dictionary that has an array (with many lists) per key. I want to turn this dictionary into a DataFrame. This is what the dictionary looks like currently:

[image]

However, the way I want it formatted is as so:

```
title                                  A       C      mC      G      T
000805ef-05c0-40d8-be27-a88ad2932a68  255     255     0      255    255
000805ef-05c0-40d8-be27-a88ad2932a68  255     20      235    255    255
......
00723b5f-95a1-44c4-93b5-ba4adb8ea5b7  255     255     0      255    255
```

I tried just simply using pd.DataFrame(dict) but that didn't work. I also tried pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict) and that didn't work either. I think I need to manipulate the dictionary more for how I want it to look in the data frame before converting. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `vstack` the values, and `repeat` the keys:

```
# dictionary with numpy arrays as values
d = {
    'a': np.ones((2, 3), dtype=np.int),
    'b': np.eye(3, dtype=np.int),
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.vstack(list(d.values())),
    index = np.repeat(
        list(d.keys()),
        [len(x) for x in d.values()]
    ),
    columns = ['x', 'y', 'z']
)

df
```

Output:

```
   x  y  z
a  1  1  1
a  1  1  1
b  1  0  0
b  0  1  0
b  0  0  1
```

Comment: Should be `list(d.values())`? as:
"FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple...:

Comment: @gbox Interesting, somehow I didn't get this warning initially, but yes, you're totally right. I've updated my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this! It got it working but it has the titles as an index column. Is there any way to have it look the same but convert the index column to an actual column called “titles”?

Comment: Sure, just add `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Really helped me out and also helped me understand what to do going forward.